# How to make modular system in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, module, laravel-4

I am trying to create a modular system in **Laravel 4.1**.

I have folders like following:

```
app
app/controllers
app/controllers/BaseController.php
app/views/
app/modules/
app/modules/moduleName/
app/modules/moduleName/routes.php
app/modules/moduleName/controllers/
app/modules/moduleName/controllers/module.php
```

When I try to extend `BaseController`, I use namespaces and I get the following error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
 Class 'Illuminate\Session' not found
```

Here is my module.php codes:

```
 <?php namespace App\Modules\Twitter\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller;

 class Modulename extends Controller {

 }
```

I have two questions.

1. How can I call session classes in modules?
2. I have route.php file in every module but still can't route the
   modules. Hence I am supposed to use laravel default routes.php file.
   How can I solve this problem?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your tree is not enough, we will need to see some code, to try understand how you're doing things and what may be happening.

Comment: I just added intro codes of my module.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel libraries all exist in the global namespace, so if you're using namespaced code of any sort, you'll need to specify the libraries you're calling.

Using the code you provided, it'd be like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\Twitter\Controllers;

 use Controller, Session;

 class Modulename extends Controller {

 }
```

This saves you having to type out the entire namespace.

Comment: Great! It worked for me. Thanks. But what about routing? (2nd question)

Comment: Well, routing is pretty easy, and Laravel works as a modular system anyway, so simply namespacing everything correctly, should suffice. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I want to add modules' own routing.php E.g.
app/modules/moduleName/routes.php
Not default laravel routes.php

Comment: just include the route files for each module in the main routes.php?